# Thread-safety for static class data members

Tags: c++

Can I assume thread-safety for static class data members in C++? In the following example, is SetCounter thread-safe?

```
class Foo {
public:
  static void SetCounter(int c) { counter = c; }  
private:
  static int counter = 0;
}
```

Comment: No, static class members don't have any magical thread-safety properties. They are simply global variables with fancy names.

Comment: To add to this; if your class has nothing but static members, you might want to consider making them non-static, putting a mutex in the class to make the class thread-safe, then having a static/singleton instance of the class instead .. as another option.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But local static variables do, and we can rely on that property when making singleton classes. Any C++ documents that explain what kinds of statics are thread-safe?

Comment: No, local static variables aren't thread-safe either. Only their initialization is, but not subsequent use.

Answer (score 1):

Thread-safety refers to making actions independent of other actions to avoid race conditions. If you have 2 threads, one  calling `SetCounter(1)` and the other calling `SetCounter(2)`, you can't guarantee what `counter` will be set to. You'd need to use a mutex/lock on the value to prevent it from being modified by other threads. If you're using libraries like boost, you can refer to the [Synchronization page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html). Otherwise, use your own mutex to toggle whether it's locked or unlocked.

Comment: I know what thread-safety is. I should have explained better where my question was coming from. See my comment above